# Installing dlib for Windows: "Failed building wheel for dlib" and "non-zero exit status 1"

Tags: python, visual-studio, dlib

I'm running Python 3.6 on Windows 10 and have installed cmake (via pip), cuda 9.2 and the latest version of Visual Studio (15.9.6), along with the 2015 v140 toolset component as it's mentioned elsewhere (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1027299/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-failed-to-support-the-latest-visual-studio-2017-version-15-5/2) that is necessary:

[image]

Upon running `pip install dlib` I get a ton of output (too much to paste here) but it includes "Failed building wheel for dlib" and the final part is as follows:

```
        9 Warning(s)
        10 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:04:17.30
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9erypcmb\dlib\setup.py", line 257, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9erypcmb\dlib\setup.py", line 133, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9erypcmb\dlib\setup.py", line 173, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_build, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\james\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\james\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9erypcmb\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-21ymtq1y\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9erypcmb\dlib\
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install in a conda environment per https://www.deciphertechnic.com/install-dlib-python-api-on-windows/